# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This my PHP code:

```
echo '<td>';
$r= $item['Rate'];
echo '<input  id="ratetb" onkeyup="clean(ratetb)" onkeydown="clean(ratetb)" name="ratetb" autocomplete="off" style="text-align:center" type="text" value="'.$r.'" >';          
echo '</td>';
```

and this is my JavaScript function:

```
function clean(e) {
    var textfield=document.getElementById(e);

    var replc=/[^0-9 .]/gi;

    textfield.value=textfield.value.replace(replc,"");
  }
```

when executes this i got error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: What should contains the `$item['Rate'];` variable?? I thing it come null from the html file.

Comment: As the error indicates, variable "textfield" is null (from which you're trying to reference the property 'value'). Therefore, "getElementById(e)" is returning null. Are you sure there is an element with ID 'e'?

Comment: Furthermore, the PHP code seems irrelevant from the info you've provided.

Comment: @HECTOR MAY BE OU ARE WRITE  $item['Rate'] RETURNS NUMBER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not passing in a string

```
echo '<input  id="ratetb" onkeyup="clean(ratetb)" onkeydown="clean(ratetb)"
```

should be

```
echo '<input  id="ratetb" onkeyup="clean(\'ratetb\')" onkeydown="clean(\'ratetb\')"
```

---

better yet, pass in the object reference

```
echo '<input  id="ratetb" onkeyup="clean(this)" onkeydown="clean(this)"
```

and change the function

```
function clean(textfield) {
    var replc=/[^0-9 .]/gi;
    textfield.value=textfield.value.replace(replc,"");
}
```

Or even better, do not use inline events.

Answer (score 2):

Please check call function and be sure there is an item with id e because error says that textfield is null so cant be value of null object.

Edit: After change your question it must be `onkeyup="clean('ratetb')"`

Comment: Yes, the strings need to be quoted as they will be seen as variables otherwise.

Comment: THE CODE REaly works fine when it is written in a normal html file